# Tizen: using Circular Genlist

Tags: tizen

I'm creating a wearable application with UI Builder in Tizen Studio.

It's said to be a convenient way of doing UI but it's a lie: because you are not allowed to edit manually the code what it's produced.

Please tell me there is some way of doing this.

In more detail: I want to have a small icon and a scrollable list below, with the Circle Genlist (list contains 6 items defined in UI Builder): https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/wearable/component-circle-genlist/

This site above states that for Circle Genlist I have to define first the normal Genlist:

```
genlist = elm_genlist_add(parent);
circle_genlist = eext_circle_object_genlist_add(genlist, surface);
```

Then I have to set the policy for scrolling:

```
eext_circle_object_genlist_scroller_policy_set(circle_genlist,
                                           ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_OFF,
                                           ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_ON);
```

And then I have to enable it:

```
eext_rotary_object_event_activated_set(circle_genlist, EINA_TRUE);
```

The UI builder adds these lines if I drop a Genlist to the panel:

```
vc->genlist1= elm_genlist_add(vc->box7);
...
vc->circle_object_genlist1= eext_circle_object_genlist_add(vc->genlist1, uib_views_get_instance()->get_window_obj()->circle_surface);
eext_rotary_object_event_activated_set(vc->circle_object_genlist1, EINA_TRUE);
```

So it seems almost pefect, but it is not setting the policy. Not a problem, just put that line there! NO. You can't because next save/run action will recreate the whole UI thus will remove your extra line, and there is no known way to avoid that. (Except creating the whole UI manually).

But! I could grab the control when the view is created, and I added these lines:

```
if(vc2->box7 && vc2->circle_object_genlist1) {
    eext_circle_object_genlist_scroller_policy_set(vc2->circle_object_genlist1, ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_ON, ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_ON);

    Elm_Genlist_Item_Class *title_itc = elm_genlist_item_class_new();
    Elm_Genlist_Item_Class *pad_itc = elm_genlist_item_class_new();

    title_itc->item_style = "title";
    title_itc->func.text_get = _gl_title_text_get;
    //title_itc->func.content_get = gl_title_icon_get;
    title_itc->func.del = NULL;

    pad_itc->item_style = "padding";
    pad_itc->func.del = NULL;

    elm_genlist_item_prepend(vc2->circle_object_genlist1, title_itc, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);
    elm_genlist_item_append(vc2->circle_object_genlist1, pad_itc, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Lines below the policy are also recommendations from the Tizen's site linked above.

However, of course, there are unknown functions need to be *reverse-engineered*. My favourite is `gl_title_icon_get`. If you search for this in Google, you will get exactly 1 result. (Or now 2, because I also mention it in this post.)

And as you might already find out: even after adding these lines, the emulator is not displaying the Circular scrollbar on the side at all.

So, I want the get something like this:

[image]

But with the nice circle scrollbar Samsung Gears have everywhere (Scrolling only the Genlist, and leaving the icon on the top):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any specialty of UI Builder but I can give you some advise about genlist widget.

1. Scroller Policy

for the circle genlist, I think you have to enable only vertical axis of scroll policy.

```
eext_circle_object_genlist_scroller_policy_set(vc2->circle_object_genlist1, ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_OFF, ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_AUTO); 
// Auto is show scroll bar when the list items can scrollable.
```

But please check this vc2->circle_object_genlist1 is proper object.
you can print the object pointer and check it is same address or not.

2. Icon title

Sadly, Genlist **title** style only have text.
to show the icon, you can use **"full"** style instead of **"title"** style.
content part name is "elm.swallow.content".

in the gl_title_icon_get callback,
check the part name is **"elm.swallow.content"** and return proper image.

so code will be,

```
    title_itc->item_style = "full";
    //title_itc->func.text_get = _gl_title_text_get;
    title_itc->func.content_get = gl_title_icon_get;
    title_itc->func.del = NULL;
```

and gl_title_icon_get will be,

```
static Evas_Object*
gl_title_icon_get(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, const char *part)
{
   if (!strcmp(part, "elm.sawllow.content"))
   {
      Evas_Object *image = elm_image_add(obj);
      elm_image_file_set(image, IMG_URL); //image resource url
      return image;
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

3. Adding title and Padding

```
 elm_genlist_item_prepend(vc2->circle_object_genlist1, title_itc, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);
    elm_genlist_item_append(vc2->circle_object_genlist1, pad_itc, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);
```

you passing vc2->circle_object_genlist1 in genlist API but it need to be genlist object not circle_genlist, so vc2->genlist1 is correct.

```
 elm_genlist_item_prepend(vc2->genlist1, title_itc, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);
    elm_genlist_item_append(vc2->genlist1, pad_itc, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, NULL);
```

please check this, and if you have more question, please reply here!
thank you.